# Making a function run after an awesomium event

Tags: c#, awesomium

I am fairly new to programming and I am working on a browser using the awesomium engine it is working well but I want to add a label which will list the URL of the site you are currently at I have this function to make the label update

```
    private void refreshurllabel()
    {
        label1.Text = webControl1.Source.ToString();
    }
```

But I need to use events to make this function run everytime a new page loads. Looking through awesomium documentation I found this event  http://docs.awesomium.net/html/E_Awesomium_Windows_Controls_WebControl_AddressChanged.htm called `AddressChanged`that would suit my needs but due to my limited knowledge I cannot work out how to make a function to run when this event is called.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wire up an event handler.  Somewhere in your code you need to add something like

`webControl1.AddressChanged += webControl1_AddressChanged;`

Then a function to handle the event

```
void webControl1_AddressChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
     webControl wc = (webControl)sender;
     label1.Text = wc.Source.ToString();
}
```